# MPAndroidChart setting the circleHoleSize on a LineChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). Is there any way to set the circleHoleSize on a linechart?
You can set the color of the hole using `LineDataSet.setCircleColorHole()` but I haven't been able to find how to change the size of the hole relative to the circleSize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's currently not possible to set the hole size individually. It always takes exactly **50%** of the circles whole size that is set.